# flutter - Text unintentionally line-broken

Tags: flutter, text, line-breaks

I am developing a web application using Flutter. and I have encountered an issue with an unknown cause.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      SelectableText(
        "พีเจ เฮ้าส์ เป็นบริษัทโครงการบ้านจัดสรรในประเทศไทย",
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        style: GoogleFonts.prompt(),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      SelectableText(
        "เราให้บริการลูกค้าด้วยบ้านที่ปลอดภัย สวยงาม และเป็นครอบครัวที่กลมเกลียวกัน\nเราจะแนะนำโครงการที่ซื่อสัตย์บนพื้นฐานของความไว้วางใจ",
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        style: GoogleFonts.prompt(),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      SelectableText(
        "สร้างอนาคตกับ พีเจ เฮ้าส์",
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        style: GoogleFonts.prompt(),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
    ],
  ),
),
```

this is my code.
But when I see the rendered screen, the text unintentionally line-breaks as follows.
[image]

It seems like the width of the Text Widget is wide enough, but it is unnecessarily line-breaking. and I've noticed the same issue with Thai text on another page, not necessarily this specific code.

If anyone knows a solution, please help.

Comment: I cant recreate your bug. I tried everything but the font. For which reason ever your text using "ะ" as line break. Maybe its because of the font?!?

Comment: The cause I've found so far seems to be related to text that contains `\n`. The bug only occurs with such text.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like bug in Chrome. The same issue is not reproducible on Firefox or Safari.

Please raise a bug on Flutter repo regarding this.

[image]

Comment: The cause I've found so far seems to be related to text that contains \n. The bug only occurs with such text.